# How to fix JeppView VFR charts font display

Tags: general-aviation, navigation, flight-planning, aeronautical-charts

Some of the VFR charts printed by [JeppView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeppesen) for Windows incorrectly display various letters on the map. This is especially visible in the NDB/DME designations ("INN", "PAT", "RUM" all rendered incorrectly):

[image]

How can I make sure all the text in the chart is displayed correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JeppView uses different proprietary fonts in its charts. If they are not embedded when the chart is saved to PDF, lettering will not display correctly.

On a Mac, [running in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4821188/7331016)

```
strings ~/Desktop/vfr_chart.pdf | grep FontName
```

returns the names of these fonts:

```
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-7-Jeppesen-Proprietary-Y
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-3-Jeppesen-Proprietary-U
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-5-Jeppesen-Proprietary-W
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-4-Jeppesen-Proprietary-V
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-6-Jeppesen-Proprietary-X
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-13-Jeppesen-Proprietary-C
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-80-Jeppesen-Proprietary-N
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-79-Jeppesen-Proprietary-M
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-77-Jeppesen-Proprietary-Y-B
/FontName /FNTSBS+Arial-BoldMT
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-11-Jeppesen-Proprietary-A
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-1-Jeppesen-Proprietary-S
/FontName /FNTSBS+FT-3-Jeppesen-Proprietary-U
```

If these fonts are not installed on another computer, some lettering will not be rendered correctly, as your PDF viewer will attempt to use the next best fonts. I have not had any luck with manually installing these fonts on computers that do not have JeppView installed, so I instead recommend:

**Always** embed the fonts when exporting charts to PDF. The tool that comes with JeppView is [NovaPDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20220519132802/https://support.jeppesen.com/article?aid=kA20z000000GvAPCA0). When printing (=exporting to PDF), toggle the option "PDF/A-1b" in the dialog window. The resulting PDF charts will display correctly on any device:

[image]